# Non void delete member function in queue class

Tags: c++, graph, queue

This is the implementation of a queue class in C++. What I cant figure out is I want a function delete in which I return the deleted element, but these errors appear:
expected unqualified-id before 'delete'
expected ; at end of member declaration

When I delete the delete function, everything works fine, but not when it is there.
I'm trying to find the shortest path in an unweighted undirected graph with bfs and I need queue, specifically a queue which returns the deleted vertex.

```
class Queue
    {
    public:
        Queue(int maxQueueSize):MaxSize(maxQueueSize)
        {
            queue=new int[MaxSize];
            front=rear=-1;
        }
        bool isFull()
        {
            if(rear==MaxSize-1)
                return true;
            else return false;
        }
        bool isEmpty()
        {
            if(front==rear)
                return true;
            else return false;
        }
        void add(const int& x)
        {
            if(isFull())
                return;
            else
                    queue[++rear]=x;
            }
          int* delete()
            {
               int& x;
                if(isEmpty())
                    return 0;
                else
                {
                    x=queue[++front];
                }
                return x;
            }
        private:
            int front,rear;
            int* queue;
            int MaxSize;
        };
```

Comment: `delete` is a reserved keyword. You can't use such a name for identifiers.

Comment: Here is a list of reserved keywords [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword). You are *not allowed* to use these names as identifiers.

Comment: `if (condition) return true else return false;` is an anti-pattern. Write `return condition;` instead!

Comment: Syntax highlighting should have tipped you on the fact that `delete` is a keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'delete' is a reserved keyword for C++.
See a list of reserved keywords [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword).

You may better call it 'remove' or something like that.
Better yet, just use a std::queue<>, it's all well written and tested for you already.

Comment: I didnt want to use the STL because the pop in the queue class returns void. Thanks :)

Comment: That's by design. You should call std::queue::front() to get the next element, then std::queue::pop() to remove it.